# Protractor test suite run all tests that are not in a folder

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

It is possible to create a test suite in Protractor by adding the following to a config file:

```
suites: {
    test1: "folder1/**/*.spec.js",
    test2: "folder2/**/*.spec.js"
}
```

Where the test suite `test1` will run all tests that are inside `folder1`.

How can I create a test suite that will run all tests that are not inside the folder `folder1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run all tests that are not inside `folder1` like this:

```
suites: {
    test: '!(folder1)/**/*.spec.js'
}
```

Protractor uses [Glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to match files from your specified `specs` or `suites` in config file.